# Can more than 1 websites be installed using Joomla?

Tags: joomla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hosting two sites within single Joomla cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424084/hosting-two-sites-within-single-joomla-cms)

I have created one website using single installation of Joomla . I want to create one more website. Is it possible to create more than 1 website ? If so how is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some components out there that will provide multisite support such as http://www.jms2win.com/